# QueryBuilder placeholder

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to reuse a `QueryBuilder` in my Elasticsearch Java Client and simply substitute in a new Id value each time it is used.

```
QueryBuilder idQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("id", "<ID PLACEHOLDER>"));
```

How can I substitute in a new Id each time I run the query? i.e. I will need to programmatically change `<ID PLACEHOLDER>` each time I run the query.

Comment: If I understood correctly you need a variable in place of "<ID PLACEHOLDER>" that will change.

Comment: yes thats correct. I think I need an example of how to create a Search Template in Java

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new instance of MatchQueryBuilder which is returned by the method call QueryBuilders.matchQuery. Currently there is no method in API to change the value of query text in the same instance of MatchQueryBuilder.

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/25254044/

value of search text is initialized only in the constructor. So you will not be able to reuse same instance of MatchQueryBuilder to create a template.